# How to get count of substring in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a string with delimiters in a column: for example:

```
 REG:aaaaa|REG:bbbbb|REG:cccc|IMP:abcd|IMP:efghi
```

The length of the column might vary with certain different inputs. I want the following output

```
length(REG) : 3
length(IMP) : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

that should be like this :

```
select 
    count(case when value like 'REG:%' then 1 end) REGcount
  , count(case when value like 'IMP:%' then 1 end) IMPcount
from split('REG:aaaaa|REG:bbbbb|REG:cccc|IMP:abcd|IMP:efghi','[|]')
```

for pattern search I'm not sure "[|]" works or "\\|". so let us know

Answer (score 0):

You can split string by `'(^|\\|)REG:'` - this regex means `'REG:'` at the beginning of the string or `'|REG:'`, then take size of array -1.

Demo for Hive:

```
select size(split(str, '(^|\\|)REG:'))-1 as REG_cnt, 
       size(split(str, '(^|\\|)IMP:'))-1 as IMP_cnt
from
(--initial data
select 'REG:aaaaa|REG:bbbbb|REG:cccc|IMP:abcd|IMP:efghi' as str
)s
```

Result:

```
reg_cnt  imp_cnt
3        2
```

For Presto/Athena:

```
select cardinality(regexp_split(str, '(^|\|)REG:'))-1 as REGcnt, 
       cardinality(regexp_split(str, '(^|\|)IMP:'))-1 as IMPcnt
from
(--initial data
select 'REG:aaaaa|REG:bbbbb|REG:cccc|IMP:abcd|IMP:efghi' as str
)s
```

Result:

```
reg_cnt  imp_cnt
3        2
```

Using this method you do not need to explode array and aggregate count.